# Rename columns while pivoting from long to wide dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I would like to convert `df` below from long to wide so that `data` for each `id` is present in a row. Currently there are 10000 rows for each unique `id`.

`df`:

```
    id  data
0   20  9.5
1   20  9.5
2   20  8.5
... ... ...

171372  118 1.0
171373  118 1.2
171374  118 1.2
```

expected output:

```
     d0   d1   d2  ... 
id
20   9.5  9.5  8.5
118  1.0  1.2  1.2
```

I tried:

```
df.pivot(index='id', columns = [i for i in range(0,10000)] , values='data')
```

It caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2888             try:
-> 2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2890             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-413-892c34c9ffea> in <module>
      1 
      2 
----> 3 df.pivot(index='id', columns = [i for i in range(0,10000)] , values='data')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   6665         from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot
   6666 
-> 6667         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   6668 
   6669     _shared_docs[

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    463             index = [data[idx] for idx in index]
    464 
--> 465         data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns]
    466         index.extend(data_columns)
    467         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    463             index = [data[idx] for idx in index]
    464 
--> 465         data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns]
    466         index.extend(data_columns)
    467         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2897             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2898                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2899             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2900             if is_integer(indexer):
   2901                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2890             except KeyError as err:
-> 2891                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2892 
   2893         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['id', df.groupby('id').cumcount()]).data.unstack().add_prefix('d')`

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you for the succinct code it's exactly what I need!